# Is there a better way to use C# dictionaries than TryGetValue?

Tags: c#, anti-patterns, code-smell, dictionary, out-parameters

I find myself often looking up questions online, and many solutions include dictionaries. However, whenever I try to implement them, I get this horrible reek in my code. For example every time I want to use a value:

```
int x;
if (dict.TryGetValue("key", out x)) {
    DoSomethingWith(x);
}
```

That's 4 lines of code to essentially do the following: `DoSomethingWith(dict["key"])`

I've heard that using the out keyword is an anti pattern because it makes functions mutate their parameters.

Also, I find myself often needing a "reversed" dictionary, where I flip the keys and values.

Similarly, I often would like to iterate through the items in a dictionary and find myself converting keys or values to lists etc to do this better.

I feel like there's almost always a better, more elegant way of using dictionaries, But I'm at a loss.

Comment: Other ways may exist but I generally use a **ContainsKey** first before trying to get a value.

Comment: If `DoSomethingWith(x)` were an extension method you could technically do: `dict.TryGetValue("key", out int x); x?.DoSomething();`  Handles the case where "key" does not exist, and still does something with x like the original code did.  But Dictionary itself is not an antipattern.  It's a collection, so its all about how you use it.

Comment: Honestly, with a few exceptions, if you know what your dictionary keys are ahead of time, there probably *is* a better way. If you don't know, the dict keys shouldn't generally be hard-coded at all. Dictionaries are useful for working with semi-structured objects or data where the fields are at least *mostly* orthogonal to the application. IMO, the closer those fields get to being relevant business/domain concepts, the less helpful dictionaries become for working with those concepts.

Comment: @RobbieDee: you have to be careful when you do that though, as doing so creates a race condition. It's possible the key could be removed between calling ContainsKey and getting the value.

Comment: @whatsisname: Under those conditions, a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) would be more suitable.  Collections in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace [are not thread-safe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.system-collections-icollection-issynchronized?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_System_Collections_ICollection_IsSynchronized).

Comment: A good 50% of the time I see someone using a `Dictionary`, what they really wanted was a new class. For those 50% (only), it's a design smell.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: agreed, though I think it's worth pointing out even that class can still suffer from race conditions if it is not carefully used, including the race condition regarding checking for existing items. The TryGet pattern is the only way that can both retrieve and test for presence atomically.

Comment: Are you wondering whether to use dictionaries at all (your question title) or whether to use them differently (your last paragraph)? These are very different questions.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch `?.` only works with nullable types though, not with ints :/

Comment: OT: You can use `foo.TryGetValue("key", out int x)` in never C# versions to save the initial variable declaration.

Comment: The antipattern is to think the .NET `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is a C#-specific element.

Comment: @MichaelPittino See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/396582/100120).

Comment: Not really related to the question, but since the language specified is C#, you could always write an Extension method that returns a default value or null

Comment: Dictionary is a pattern, but abusing them can create any possible sort of antipattern. Try G-ing for `dictionary site:thedailywtf.com` for some humour

Comment: You have at least three questions in here, and as usually happens in that scenario, people are picking and choosing which question to answer. Try to clarify your questions so that you're asking a single question; it's OK to post multiple questions if you have multiple questions.

Comment: " using the out keyword is an anti pattern because it makes functions mutate their parameters." - that's an interesting point of view... Since `out` is essentially second `return` do you consider regular `return` also making "function to mutate their parameters"?

Comment: I agree which is why I often use this GetOrNull extension method (not applicable for value types): public static TValue GetOrNull<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key) where TValue : class => dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue val) ? val : null;

Comment: `out` does not mutate a parameter, you are probably thinking of `ref`. Out does not pass anything in, so the question of mutation is moot. It is just a way to return ore than one value from a method. It is kind of ugly but it is not an antipattern, and in this case it is the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Dictionaries (C# or otherwise) are simply a container where you look up a value based on a key.  In many languages it's more correctly identified as a Map with the most common implementation being a HashMap.

The problem to consider is what happens when a key does not exist.  Some languages behave by returning `null` or `nil` or some other equivalent value.  Silently defaulting to a value instead of informing you that a value does not exist.

For better or for worse, the C# library designers came up with an idiom to deal with the behavior.  They reasoned that the default behavior for looking up a value that does not exist is to throw an exception.  If you want to avoid exceptions, then you can use the `Try` variant.  It's the same approach they use for parsing strings into integers or date/time objects.  Essentially, the impact is like this:

```
T count = int.Parse("12T45"); // throws exception

if (int.TryParse("12T45", out count))
{
    // Does not throw exception
}
```

And that carried forward to the dictionary, whose indexer delegates to `Get(index)`:

```
var myvalue = dict["12345"]; // throws exception
myvalue = dict.Get("12345"); // throws exception

if (dict.TryGet("12345", out myvalue))
{
    // Does not throw exception
}
```

This is simply the way the language is designed.

---

**Should `out` variables be discouraged?**

C# isn't the first language to have them, and they have their purpose in specific situations.  If you are trying to build a highly concurrent system, then you cannot use `out` variables at the concurrency boundaries.

In many ways, if there is an idiom that is espoused by the language and core library providers, I try to adopt those idioms in my APIs.  That makes the API feel more consistent and at home in that language.  So a method written in Ruby isn't going to look like a method written in C#, C, or Python.  They each have a preferred way of building code, and working with that helps the users of your API learn it more quickly.

---

**Are Maps in General an Anti-pattern?**

They have their purpose, but many times they may be the wrong solution for the purpose you have.  Particularly if you have a bi-directional mapping you need.  There are many containers and ways of organizing data.  There are many approaches that you can use, and sometimes you need to think a bit before you pick that container.

If you have a very short list of bi-directional mapping values, then you might only need a list of tuples.  Or a list of structs, where you can just as easily find the first match on either side of the mapping.

Think of the problem domain, and pick the most appropriate tool for the job.  If there isn't one, then create it.

Comment: "then you might only need a list of tuples. Or a list of structs, where you can just as easily find the first match on either side of the mapping."  --  If there are optimizations for small sets, they should be made in the library, not rubber-stamped into user code.

Comment: If you choose a list of tuples or a dictionary, that is an implementation detail.  It's a question of understanding your problem domain and using the right tool for the job.  Obviously, a list exists and a dictionary exists.  For the common case, dictionary is correct, but maybe for one or two applications you need to use the list.

Comment: It is, but if the behavior is still the same, that determination should be in the library.  I've run across containers implementations in other languages that will switch algorithms if told _a priori_ that the number of entries will be small.  I agree with your answer, but once this has been figured out, it should be in a library, maybe as a SmallBidirectionalMap.

Comment: "For better or for worse, the C# library designers came up with an idiom to deal with the behavior." – I think you hit the nail on the head: they "came up" with an idiom, instead of using an existing widely-used one, which is an optional return type.

Comment: There is no `Get()` method on `Dictionary<K, V>`, so the indexer can't possibly delegate to it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you're talking about something like `Option<T>`, then I think that would make the method much harder to use in C# 2.0, because it didn't have pattern matching.

Comment: @svick: I like Pattern Matching, but it is still Just A Conditional. It's not needed here. `Option` is a monad, it is isomorphic to a collection of at most one element. It can just implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and you can use it like a collection. In particular, you can `foreach` over it, which will either execute the body once if the value exists or not at all if it doesn't. Or, you can `map` it to transform the value if it exists, `flatmap` it, etc. With newer versions of C♯ and the BCL, you would get the full power of LINQ, but again, that is not necessary. All you need is `foreach`.

Comment: I'm of the opinion out variables should be discouraged, that said its only a readability preference not a dangerous anti-pattern. TryGet has a significant peformance benefit in that it does the key/value search only once, doing a contains call followed by a seperate get is going to be around half the speed.

Answer (score 35):

Some good answers here on the general principles of hashtables/dictionaries. But I thought I'd touch on your code example,

```
int x;
if (dict.TryGetValue("key", out x)) 
{
    DoSomethingWith(x);
}
```

As of C# 7 (which I think is around two years old), that can be simplified to:

```
if (dict.TryGetValue("key", out var x))
{
    DoSomethingWith(x);
}
```

And of course it could be reduced to one line:

```
if (dict.TryGetValue("key", out var x)) DoSomethingWith(x);
```

If you have a default value for when the key doesn't exist, it can become:

```
DoSomethingWith(dict.TryGetValue("key", out var x) ? x : defaultValue);
```

So you can achieve compact forms by using reasonably recent language additions.

Comment: Good call on the v7 syntax, nice little option to have to cut out the extra definition line while allowing the use of var +1

Comment: Note also that if `"key"` is not present, `x` will be initialized to `default(TValue)`

Comment: Might be nice as a generic extension, too, invoked like `"key".DoSomethingWithThis()`

Comment: I greatly prefer designs that use `getOrElse("key", defaultValue)` [Null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) is still my favorite pattern. Work that way and you don't care if `TryGetValue` returns true or false.

Comment: @candied_orange, then add `public static TValue GetOrElse<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue defaultValue) => dict.TryGetValue(key, out var x) ? x : defaultValue);` to a static class in your project and you've got that :)

Comment: I feel like this answer deserves a disclaimer that writing compact code for the sake of it being compact is bad. It can make your code much harder to read. Additionally, if I recall correctly, `TryGetValue` is not atomic/thread safe so you could just as easily perform one check for existence and another to grab and operate on the value

Comment: @Marie, indeed the whole of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is not thread-safe. Use the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` type if thread safety is needed.

Answer (score 16):

This is neither a code smell nor an anti-pattern, as using TryGet-style functions with an out parameter is idiomatic C#. However, there are 3 options provided in C# to work with a Dictionary, so should you be sure you are using the correct one for your situation. I think I know where the rumor of there being a problem using an out parameter comes from, so I'll handle that at the end.

What features to use when working with a C# Dictionary:

1. If you are sure the key will be in the Dictionary, use the Item[TKey] property
2. If the key should generally be in the Dictionary, but it is bad/rare/problematic that it is not there, you should use Try...Catch so that an error will be raised and then you can try to handle the error gracefully
3. If you are not sure the key will be in the Dictionary, use TryGet with the out parameter

To justify this, one need only refer to the [documentation for Dictionary TryGetValue, under "Remarks"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> **This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and the Item[TKey] property.**
>
> ...
>
> Use the TryGetValue method if your code frequently attempts to access
>   keys that are not in the dictionary. Using this method is more
>   efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown by the
>   Item[TKey] property.
>
> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

The whole reason TryGetValue exists is to act as a more convenient way to use ContainsKey and Item[TKey], while avoiding having to search the dictionary twice - so pretending it doesn't exist and doing the two things it does manually is a rather awkward choice.

In practice, I rarely have ever used a raw Dictionary, due to this simple maxim: choose the most generic class/container *that gives you the functionality you need*. Dictionary was not designed to look up by value rather than by key (for example), so if that is something you want it may make more sense to use an alternate structure. I think I may have used Dictionary one time in the last year-long development project I did, simply because it was rarely the right tool for the job I was trying to do. Dictionary is certainly not the Swiss Army knife of the C# toolbox.

**What's wrong with out parameters?**

[CA1021: Avoid out parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1021-avoid-out-parameters?view=vs-2019)

> Although return values are commonplace and heavily used, the correct
>   application of out and ref parameters requires intermediate design and
>   coding skills. Library architects who design for a general audience
>   should not expect users to master working with out or ref parameters.

I'm guessing that's where you heard that out parameters were something like an anti-pattern. As with all rules, you should read closer to understand the 'why', and in this case there is even an explicit mention of [how the Try pattern does not violate the rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1021-avoid-out-parameters?view=vs-2019#try-pattern-methods):

> Methods that implement the Try pattern, such as
>   System.Int32.TryParse, do not raise this violation.

Comment: That whole list of guidance is something I wish more people would read. For those who follow, here's the root of it. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/design-warnings?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 13):

There are at least two methods missing from C# dictionaries that in my opinion clean up code considerably in a lot of situations in other languages. The first is returning an `Option`, which lets you write code like the following in Scala:

```scala
dict.get("key").map(doSomethingWith)
```

The second is returning a user-specified default value if the key isn't found:

```scala
doSomethingWith(dict.getOrElse("key", "key not found"))
```

There is something to be said for using the idioms a language provides when appropriate, like the `Try` pattern, but that doesn't mean you have to *only* use what the language provides. We're programmers. It's okay to create new abstractions to make our specific situation easier to understand, especially if it eliminates a lot of repetition. If you frequently need something, like reverse lookups or iterating through values, make it happen. Create the interface you wish you had.

Comment: I like the 2nd option. Maybe I'll have to write an extension method or two :)

Comment: on the plus side c# extension methods means you can implement these yourself

Answer (score 8):

> That's 4 lines of code to essentially do the following: `DoSomethingWith(dict["key"])`

I agree that this is inelegant. A mechanism that I like to use in this case, where the value is a struct type, is:

```
public static V? TryGetValue<K, V>(
      this Dictionary<K, V> dict, K key) where V : struct => 
  dict.TryGetValue(key, out V v) ? new V?(v) : new V?();
```

Now we have a new version of `TryGetValue` that returns `int?`.  We can then do a similar trick for extending `T?`:

```
public static void DoIt<T>(
      this T? item, Action<T> action) where T : struct
{
  if (item != null) action(item.GetValueOrDefault());
}
```

And now put it together:

```
dict.TryGetValue("key").DoIt(DoSomethingWith);
```

and we're down to a single, clear statement.

> I've heard that using the out keyword is an anti pattern because it makes functions mutate their parameters.

I would be slightly less strongly worded, and say that avoiding mutations when possible is a good idea.

> I find myself often needing a "reversed" dictionary, where I flip the keys and values.

Then implement or obtain a bidirectional dictionary. They are straightforward to write, or there are plenty of implementations available on the internet. There are a bunch of implementations here, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c-sharp

> Similarly, I often would like to iterate through the items in a dictionary and find myself converting keys or values to lists etc to do this better.

Sure, we all do.

> I feel like there's almost always a better, more elegant way of using dictionaries, But I'm at a loss.

Ask yourself "suppose I had a class other than `Dictionary` that implemented the exact operation that I wish to do; what would that class look like?"  Then, once you've answered that question, **implement that class**.  You're a computer programmer. Solve your problems by writing computer programs!

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you could go into a bit more explanation of what the action method is actually doing? I’m new to actions.

Comment: @AdamB an action is an object that represents the ability to call a void method. As you see, on the caller side we pass the name of a void method whose parameter list matches the generic type arguments of the action. On the caller side the action is invoked like any other method.

Comment: @AdamB: You can think of `Action<T>` as being very similar to `interface IAction<T> { void Invoke(T t); }`, but with very lenient rules about what "implements" that interface, and about how `Invoke` may be invoked. If you want to know more, learn about "delegates" in C#, and then learn about lambda expressions.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. So the action let’s you put a method in as the parameter for DoIt(). And calls that method.

Comment: @AdamB: Exactly right. This is an example of "functional programming with higher-order functions". Most functions take data as arguments; higher-order functions take *functions* as arguments and then do stuff with those functions. As you learn more C# you'll see that LINQ is entirely implemented with higher-order functions.

Comment: Fyi there's an extra parenthesis in `TryGetValue(key, out V v))`

Answer (score 3):

The `TryGetValue()` construct is only necessary if you don't know whether "key" is present as a key within the dictionary or not, otherwise `DoSomethingWith(dict["key"])` is perfectly valid.

A "less dirty" approach might be to use `ContainsKey()` as a check instead.

Comment: "A "less dirty" approach might be to use ContainsKey() as a check instead." I disagree. As suboptimal as `TryGetValue` is, at least it makes it hard to forget to handle the empty case. Ideally, I wish this would just return an Optional.

Comment: @Alexander how would you handle the case where the dictionary values themselves are optional/nullable?

Comment: @Alexander, blatant self-promotion here, but what you need is my [Succinct library](https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT/wiki/IDictionaryExtensions) which includes a `TryGetValue` extension method that returns an `Option<T>` :)

Comment: There's a potential problem with the `ContainsKey` approach for multithreaded applications, which is time of check to time of use (TOCTOU) vulnerability. What if some other thread deletes the key between the calls to `ContainsKey` and `GetValue`?

Comment: @JAD Optionals compose. You can have an `Optional<Optional<T>>`

Comment: @Alexander sounds like java tbh. `Nullable<T>` in C# only accepts previously non-nullable types.

Comment: @DavidHammen To be clear, you would need `TryGetValue` on `ConcurrentDictionary`. The regular dictionary wouldn't be synchronized

Comment: @JAD No, (Java's optional type blows, don't get me started). I'm talking more abstractly

Comment: @Alexander ah, gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers contain great points, so I won't restate them here, but instead I'll focus on this part, which seems to be largely ignored so far:

> Similarly, I often would like to iterate through the items in a dictionary and find myself converting keys or values to lists etc to do this better.

Actually, it's pretty easy to iterate over a dictionary, since it does implement `IEnumerable`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach ( var item in dict ) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

If you prefer Linq, that too works out just fine:

```
dict.Select(x=>x.Value).WhateverElseYouWant();
```

All in all, I don't find Dictionaries to be an antipattern - they're just a specific tool with specific uses.

Also, for even more specifics, check out [`SortedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) (uses R-B trees for a more predictable performance) and [`SortedList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8) (which is also a confusingly named dictionary that sacrifices insertion speed for lookup speed, but shines if you're staring out with a fixed, pre-sorted set). I've had a case where replacing a `Dictionary` with a `SortedDictionary` resulted in an order of magnitude faster execution (but it could happen the other way round too).

Answer (score 2):

If you feel using a dictionary is awkward it may not be the right choice for your problem. Dictionaries are great but like one commenter noticed, often they are used as a shortcut for something that should have been a class. Or the dictionary itself may be right as a core storage method but there should be a wrapper class around it to provide the desired service methods.

A lot has been said about Dict[key] versus TryGet. What I use a lot is iterating over the dictionary using KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>. Apparently this is a less commonly known construct.

The main boon of a dictionary is that it is really fast compared to other collections as the number of items grows. If you often find yourself checking whether a key exists or not you may want to ask yourself if your use of a dictionary is appropriate. As a client you should typically know what you put in there and thus what would be safe to query.

Comment: *really fast* could do with some qualification

Comment: @CaiusJard  Fast as in O(1). It practically doesn't matter how many items are in the collection, a requested item will be returned in a constant time that does not increase as the number of items grows.

Comment: I was curious because it's used in a sentence talking about growth; there's the build/maintenance aspect too because a dictionary uses arrays internally, that it has to grow occasionally, and there's a reasonable amount more juggling that a dictionary does during growth that e.g. a list and e.e.g. definitely a linkedlist doesn't do. A minor consideration too is that, AIUI, colliding hashes essentially store in something more like a linked list, and it's not a straight out hash code collision but the modulo of the size of the dictionary's buckets that matters so you can have quite a lot of ..

Comment: .. linked list style behavior. (It would be unfortunate, but I believe it's entirely possible to have a dictionary where every element has the same modhash and hence it will behave like a list, i.e. O(n), because it will have to loop through every colliding item using Equals on the key to find the one you asked for)

Comment: @CaiusJard  "possible to have a dictionary where every element has the same modhash "  That is not a practical scenario. Hash collisions are rare, the number of items in a bucket will be small for any serious dictionary implementation and the increased access times negligible. You would need to create a dictionary with a humongous amount of items before this would become an issue. You will run out of memory sooner.

Comment: *That is not a practical scenario* - you're free to differ, but I'm sure it is; I just created a `Dictionary<string,string>` right now with keys of `n`, `u` and `j` that had very different hashcodes (-1618820888, 13355197 and 362770326) but every single one of them wound up in the same bucket and were hence put to a linked list.. I think you might be overlooking that it's the number of buckets, not the range of the hashcode, that arranges for collisions to occur. Every collection is some kind of trade-off..

Comment: @CaiusJard  I do not understand what you are saying. A different hash code would imply a different bucket. What tells you your items are in the same bucket? A better test would be to compare (average) access times for 10 items vs 1 million items.

Answer (score 1):

This was bugging me too, so I came up with this extension:

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the [framework provided method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-8.0) have shortcomings?